# Get parent directory name and filename without extension from full filepath in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a long file path, like

```
 /path/to/file/dir1/dir2/file.txt.gz
```

I am interested in getting the file name without the last extension (i.e., `file.txt`), and the name of the parent directory (`dir2`, I don't want the full path to the parent directory, just its name).

How can I do this in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using BASH:

```
s='/path/to/file/dir1/dir2/file.txt.gz'

file="${s##*/}"
file="${file%.*}"
echo "$file"
file.txt

filder="${s%/*}"
folder="${folder##*/}"
echo "$folder"
dir2
```

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F '/' '{sub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", $NF); print $(NF-1), $NF}' <<< "$s"
dir2 file.txt
```

To read them into shell variables:

```
read folder file < <(awk -F '/' '{sub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", $NF);print $(NF-1), $NF}'<<<"$s")
```

Comment: I have no idea what that means. Can you store the results (the dirname and the file name without last extension) into two variables, `file` and `folder`? That way I can do something useful with it. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the answer with BASHism also. You can just use: `file="${p%.*}"` and `folder="${d##*/}"` instead of `echo` statements above.

Answer (score 2):

The first part can be solved by basename(1):

```
$ basename /path/to/file/dir1/dir2/file.txt.gz
file.txt.gz
$
```

dirname(1) does the opposite, which is not quite what you want, but maybe you can use that as a starting point:

```
$ dirname /path/to/file/dir1/dir2/file.txt.gz
/path/to/file/dir1/dir2
$
```

Of course, you can always use Perl:

```
$ perl -E 'do { @p=split m|/|; say $p[-2] } for @ARGV' /path/to/file/dir1/dir2/file.txt.gz
dir2
$
```